# How change color of all texts on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new at flutter and today I'm testing some things like change texts and functions. But now I have a question, how can I change the color of all the texts? I've changed the background to black, but can't change the color font and don't want to change in every Text().

This is my code at now:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'El Grandioso Countador e Parificador',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'El Grandioso Countador e Parificador'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  var _color = Colors.white;
  String _pi = "0 não é par nem ímpar";

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _pi = _counter % 2 == 0 ? "par" : "ímpar";
      _color = _pi == "par" ? Colors.blue : Colors.red;
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black, //Here I'm changing the entire background to black, but the text are black too, so I can't read anything on my app.
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Nusha, sabe quantas vezes tu clicou no botão lá? Olha ae:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            Text(
              _pi == '0 não é par nem ímpar'
                  ? '$_pi'
                  : 'Rapash, teu número é $_pi',
              style: TextStyle(color: _color),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Clicador',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've searched but nothing come to solved my question. Someone have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

The `ThemeData` class has a `textTheme` attribute you can set.

Try this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'El Grandioso Countador e Parificador',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        textTheme: TextTheme(headline4: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'El Grandioso Countador e Parificador'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This just change the text of the _counter. I understand why (The field Text have a "style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4" and we change the textTheme for headline4. But what I want is change for All the texts;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextTheme.apply` in `textTheme` and set color for bodyColor and displayColor like code below:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'El Grandioso Countador e Parificador',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
                bodyColor: Colors.red,
                displayColor: Colors.red,
              )),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'El Grandioso Countador e Parificador'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This have worked fine with what I have. But I just need the bodyColor, this actually have changed the color of all the texts but the displayColor don't do nothing, what is supossed to do? I used in my code the "scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black" to change the color of background to black.

Comment: Each of these attributes use for some TextStyles. When you set color for both of them, it changes all of your texts colors.